# What can I do with the LINQPad.Runtime?

Tags: linqpad, linqpad7

Just learning about LINQPad and I am trying to do understand what I can do with the [`LINQPad.Runtime`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LINQPad.Runtime/) NuGet package. Where can I find the docs for this? Also, is this package the right one for NET6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reference this package from a Visual Studio project, you can call `Util.ToHtmlString` to format objects as HTML via the `Dump` pipeline. You can also call `Util.Run` to execute LINQPad scripts - this makes it easier to pass parameters to the script and receive return values than shelling out to lprun.

LINQPad.Runtime works all versions of .NET >= .NET Core 3.1.